# file upload required asterisk symbol get removed after upload file

Tags: 8, webforms

I created a file element in a webform and set it required in condition that if  select element (name as request type) value ="Yes". So when I select type value 'Yes' the file label showing asterisk symbol
Attachment * but when I upload an file the asterisk symbol get removed and label become Attachment only. In case if i submit the form asterisk symbol appears as well. Can anyone having same issue and fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Just to confirm, do you mean "asterisk"?

Comment: @Clive Yes I mean it